# Calling custom apex as REST with XML results

Tags: apex, api, xml, http, rest

So you want to call your Apex classes from outside salesforce via RESTful HTTP and need XML resurned even though it's uncool. The official [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/api_rest.pdf) suggests it's supported by simply adding the `Accept: text/xml` header to your requests. My tests today show this not to be the case. Indeed this header does nothing to get you XML back and there are 2 different ways depending on whether you are doing a login or calling your code.

If you use `Accept: text/xml` without the tricks described below you will not get XML. For the login (/token) service you get JSON but for calling your own apex you get the following error:

```
[{"message":"Accept header specified in HTTP request is not supported: text/xml","errorCode":"NOT_ACCEPTABLE"}]
```

I realise the solutions below are documented in various places but I hope having the answer here in one place (with error messages) helps others!

Answer (score 4):

**1. Login Procedure**

For the login procedure `POST` is used. Here you have to add the parameter `format=xml` to your request body.

```
POST https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.0
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
content-length: 256
accept: */*
user-agent: Whateva
host: test.salesforce.com

grant_type=password&format=xml&client_id=***.***&client_secret=***&username=user%40domain.com.dev1&password=*****TOKEN
```

This will get you your "token" or session id which you pass below as the `Authorization` header.

**2. Calling Classes**

Here, again, adding an `Accept` header does nothing. Instead add the `.xml` suffix to your class name (so the class `zrest.cls` is called as `zrest.xml`):

```
GET https://cs8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/zrest.xml HTTP/1.0
content-length: 0
authorization: OAuth ****!****
user-agent: Whateva
host: cs8.salesforce.com
```